# Conjecture about $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|1+\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|=0$

Tags: inequalities, trigonometric-sums

Ps: I have reached the number of question I can propose so let this here please .And it's a work on open questions .

Does we have in radians :

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|1+\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|=0$$

Some arguments in the right sense :

Let $n$ sufficiently large such that $0<\tan(n)<\sqrt{n}$ then it seems we have :

$$\left|1+\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$

Let $C$ be the number of solutions of $\tan(n)>\sqrt{n}$ then it seems we have for $n$ sufficiently large :

$$C<K\ln^2(n)$$

Where $K$ is superior or equal to one .

Moreover and again for $n$ sufficiently large such that $\tan(n)>\sqrt{n}$ it seems we have :

$$\left|1+\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|<1+\frac{\left(n^{\frac{11}{10}}+1\right)}{\frac{n}{4}}$$

We have for $k+1<N$ and $N$ large enought :

$$-\left(N-k\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}+\sum_{n=k}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<0$$

Combining all this informations and using the theorem see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536705/do-we-have-prod-n-1-infty-left1-frac-tan-leftn-right1n-left-tan my answer with telescoping (in the start)

It seems $\exists k,M$ two positives integers and $M$ sufficiently large :

$$\sum_{n=k}^{M}\left|1+\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|<\left(M-k\right)\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(M-k\right)^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}+4\frac{\ln^{2}\left(M\right)-C}{(M-k)^{0.9}}\right)^{\frac{1}{M}}\left(1+\frac{k!\left(\tan\left(1\right)+1\right)}{M!\left(\tan\left(M+1\right)+1\right)}\right)\right|^{M}$$

Where $C$ is the number of solutions of $\tan(n)>\sqrt{n}$ for $n\leq M-k$

It leads currently for $k$sufficiently large and $k+1<M$ :

$$\prod_{n=k}^{M}\left|1+\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{\left(M-k\right)^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}+4\frac{\ln^{2}\left(M\right)-C}{(M-k)^{0.9}}\right)^{M-k}$$

Wich is very crude .

Side notes :

We can highly improving it replacing in the second inequality $<1+1/n$ or $1-1/n$ when we can

@FedorPetrov I stop to do maths here so be comprehensive the next question I can propose is in 3 month or more .Thanks you .

Also I'm thankfull to @Andreas for the bound $\tan(n)<n^{1.1}$ and @Ivan Kaznacheyeu for the this useful remark see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542968/conjecture-about-n-tan-leftn1-right-tan-leftn-right1n-n-tann1n and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499533/show-tann-nq-conjectured-q-1-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Be gentle please .

---

As in we know recently that for $n$ an integer :

$$\tan(n)<n^{6.11}$$ then for $m$ large enought using the Cauchy criterion for convergence of infinite product  :

$$|1+\prod_{n=m}^{m+k}\left|\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|-1|<\varepsilon$$

Then :

$$\prod_{n=m}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right|=0$$

So now it's related to the symetric polynomials the problem being at least for $a_0$ to $a_6$

recalling the value above ($6.11$)

So now I'm thinking it diverges ...

Comment: Please ask a question explicitly. A claim is not a question.

Comment: Have you proved that $h''\le q''$?

Comment: Why did you completely overwrite the question instead of asking a new one??

Comment: The angles $\alpha$ such that $\tan(\alpha)+1$ and $\tan(\alpha+1)+1$ have opposite signs are half of the interval $[0,\pi]$ (in measure). So the fraction should be negative half of the times (in density). Is there a reason why the effect of negative terms is stronger?

Comment: You mean that the function must be logarithmically concave on each interval $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1)$, right?

Comment: again a different question, please stop doing this, ask new questions without removing old

Comment: I think it's unclear that there is no subsequence of $n$'s for which $\left|\frac{\tan\left(n\right)+1}{n\tan\left(n+1\right)+n}\right| $ goes to infinity; even if the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is $2$ there are stil infinitely many $n$ for which $|\cos n| <<1/n$ and then $|\tan (n+1)|$ is not small so the term in the bracket is $>> \delta >1$ infinitely many times

Comment: Is it really true that there is a limit to the number of questions one can ask on MO? I have not heard of that...

Comment: @SamHopkins There are limits like: number of questions asked per day, or per week, and so on.  Perhaps depending on your reputation.  Perhaps Erik has reached the limit in math.se, but not in MO.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_conjecture